# How to find a list of users in a specific department using LDAP

Tags: asp.net, active-directory, ldap, directoryservices, directorysearcher

How do I get a list of all the users in a specific department using DirectorySearcher and Filter/PropertiesToLoad?

I know how to filter using a username and get the department name for a user, but I do not know how to specify a department and get a list of staff who are part of the department.

Any assistance appreciated!

e.g.

```
var search = new DirectorySearcher(new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://DC=au,DC=company,DC=com"));
search.Filter = "(sAMAccountName=" + userID + ")"; // put the identity name here
search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("cn");
search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("department");
var res = search.FindOne();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use the old-style `DirectorySearcher`, then the trick is to bind to the OU that you want to list the users for, e.g. your deparment:

```
var searchRoot = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://OU=YourDepartment,DC=au,DC=company,DC=com");
var search = new DirectorySearcher(searchRoot);
```

and then do a

```
search.FindAll();
```

and iterate over the results.

The other option would be to use the newer `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` namespace and use it's strongly-typed, easy-to-use classes such as the `PrincipalSearcher` and a "query-by-example" principal to do your searching:

```
// create your domain context and define a "starting" container where to search in
using (PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "YOURDOMAIN", "OU=YourDepartment,DC=au,DC=company,DC=com"))
{
   // define a "query-by-example" principal - here, we search for a UserPrincipal 
   // and with the first name (GivenName) of "Bruce" and a last name (Surname) of "Miller"
   UserPrincipal qbeUser = new UserPrincipal(ctx);
   qbeUser.GivenName = "Bruce";
   qbeUser.Surname = "Miller";

   // create your principal searcher passing in the QBE principal    
   PrincipalSearcher srch = new PrincipalSearcher(qbeUser);

   // find all matches
   foreach(var found in srch.FindAll())
   {
       // do whatever here - "found" is of type "Principal" - it could be user, group, computer.....          
   }
}
```

If you haven't already - absolutely read the MSDN article [Managing Directory Security Principals in the .NET Framework 3.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc135979.aspx) which shows nicely how to make the best use of the new features in `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement`. Or see the [MSDN documentation on the System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.aspx) namespace.

Of course, depending on your need, you might want to specify other properties on that "query-by-example" user principal you create:

- `DisplayName` (typically: first name + space + last name)
- `SAM Account Name` - your Windows/AD account name
- `User Principal Name` - your "username@yourcompany.com" style name

You can specify any of the properties on the `UserPrincipal` and use those as "query-by-example" for your `PrincipalSearcher`.

**Update:** to get the members of a group, use this code:

```
// set up domain context
using (PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
{
    // find the group in question
    GroupPrincipal group = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, "YourGroupNameHere");

    // if found....
    if (group != null)
    {
       // iterate over members
       foreach (Principal p in group.GetMembers())
       {
           Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", p.StructuralObjectClass, p.DisplayName);
           // do whatever you need to do to those members
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Instead of looking for staff within a department, what I'm actually looking for is a list of staff within a particular AD group (a group we made up). Would I still be using the same solution in this case? it doesn't seem to work for me..

Comment: @viv_acious: no, a group is different from an OU. A group **has members** - it doesn't **contain users**. You'll need to find the group and then get its members. I'll updated my post....

Comment: Thank you SO much marc_s. I will give it a try now and let you know. Much appreciated your help!

Comment: Hi @marc_s, just wanted to ask you something related to this - if a group has members AND nested sub-groups (and each subgroup has their own members and nested subgroups), how would I change the solution? Really would appreciate your help on this!